# Interpolate background colors using DirectX 11?

Tags: c++, animation, directx, interpolation

I have a task to make an application which background color should be changing between 3 random colors, creating blinking effect and smoothly interpolating between 3 colors along the sine curve.

- Curve position at -1 - window background is 100% color A;
- Curve position at 0 - window background is 100% color B
- Curve position at 1 - window background is 100% color C
- Other curve positions should be smoothly interpolated between these colors (ex.: at -0.5 background color should be 50% color A and 50% color B);

How should this interpolation and color change be implemented along the curve?

I have read about Vertex and Pixel Shaders, Effects and writing a function for a sine curve is not a problem, just don't understand at this stage how to connect them in code to make this effect achievable while moving along the curve.

Comment: What exactly is the part that you're struggling with? What do you have so far, and what's not working like you want it to (what exactly do you want it to do and what is it doing instead)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M... if I have understood what you need to do you have only to use the DirectX Lib to display the color.

I believe you have some knowledge of coding.

First, you don't need shaders, all you need for this job regarding DirectX can be found here: [DirectX 2D Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct2d/getting-started-with-direct2d)

This tutorial shows you how to draw a square using DirectX, to make DirectX works you need to do some pre-configuration in order to lock the GPU, but this is explained in the tutorial.

However for what I read from your question, you are not proficient with Computer graphics, so maybe you need some basic info to work out this tutorial.
I think you need some, tutorials about graphics coordinates, world coordinate, relative coordinate.

Passed this part the rest is quite straight forward, the interpolation of colors can be seen as a vector interpolation (a color is a 3-dimensional vector RedBlueGeen, or 4 dimensional with the Alpha channel), while you have to use the sin with the system timer to generate the blinking effect:

```
color = interpolate(color1,color2, percentual)
```

The percentual is the result of percentual=sin(timer), the timer can be obtained from the system, but you have to be careful, because the DirectX call the draw function you write when it can, so you have to do some calculation to smooth this problem and remember to shift the sin function or swap the colors.

The last thing you need is then to obtain the dimension of the windows, and use it to draw a square large as the window of your program.